# Making ajax post to ASP.NET MVC endpoint with superagent, bind to IEnumerable<int> property

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, superagent

Making Ajax post request to ASP.NET MVC3 endpoint by superagent. UserName bounds correctly and comes as 'foobar'.
However, RoleIds (IEnumerable < int> ) comes as null.

My current implementation looks like this:

Server: (C#, MVC3)

```
public class AddUserViewModel 
{
  public string UserName { get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<int> RoleIds { get; set; }
}  

public class UserManagementController : Controller {
    ...
    [HttpPost]        
    public virtual ActionResult AddUser(AddUserViewModel addUserViewModel) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Client (Javascript):

```
const data = {
    UserName: 'foobar',
    RoleIds: [1, 2]
}

superagent.post('/AddUser')
.send(data)
.then((res) => console.log(res))
```

My request looks like this:

```
{"UserName":"foobar","RoleIds":[1,2]}
```

What I have learnt I guess I have to post my request in the following format:

```
UserName=foobar&RoleIds=1&RoleIds=2
```

How to make superagent to format the request in the correct format in order to MVC3 endpoint to bind it correctly? (In jQuery there was some `traditional` option to deal with this.)

Comment: You would need to stringfy the data () and set the content type to `application/json` (I'm guessing that would be `.send(JSON.stringify(data))` and `.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')`)

Comment: Alternatively generate the data as `data = { UserName: 'foobar', RoleIds[1]: 1, RoleIds[0]: 2 }`

Comment: Unfortunately it still comes as null if I generate it as ```data = { UserName: 'foobar', RoleIds[1]: 1, RoleIds[0]: 2 }```. However  ```data = { UserName: 'foobar', RoleIds: 1 }``` works and RolesIds binds but it's, of course, only one item array which won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it working.

One should set `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then it sends the request in correct format like this:

`UserName=foobar&RoleIds=1&RoleIds=2`

So the request must be done like this:

```
const data = {
  UserName: 'foobar',
  RoleIds: [1, 2]
}

superagent.post('/AddUser')
.send(data)
.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
.then((res) => console.log(res))
```